# Transferring billiard game state from player to player with box2d

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, network-programming, starling-framework

Im using Union server for my iOS (Starling) billiard game.

[image]

So far the connections work great.

My question is:

1. How would you handle the transfer of the ball positions from the opponent.

Lets say I make the break, and I want to copy that shot to the other player?

2. Do you think its a good idea to send a message over union every frame (x, y)?

Will this cause latency problems?

Comment: just an idea off the top of my head, if the physics engine is entirely predictable, then in theory putting in the same shot on both sides should result in the exact same physics result? Then could just do a sync check when everything has stopped moving, instead of having to send all the data over every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First about your question:

The game is installed on both devices, the rules are same. So on shot send the white balls force and all other properties you modify. On the receiving device add that force etc. and the ball will repeat the action done by the sending user.

Now the sad part:

I will be the first one to disappoint you - even if you solve your problem and send the message from player to player with out problems the result won't be pleasant: box2d calculations are optimised for performance, but the result will differ as it's calculated with approximate accuracy. As a result even on the same device the balls will end up in a different location on different runs. You won't notice it in one-two hits, but after playing for a minute you'll end up with deferent ball locations.
You can also try to send a message of every ball position in space after all balls stop moving and relocate the remote users ball positions. After that "correcting" message was received return the control to the player.

We had a similar game and I just wrote my own 2d engine. If you're working only with ball to ball and ball to rectangle collisions it's easy to write your own engine.

Comment: thx for the extensive answer, I came accross this problem, what server side would you recommend that has a relatively low latency?

Comment: latency means it will take longer before the receiving player gets the message from the server/peer. Just fake movements of the virtual cue. Tween it or something to fake the effect of player thinking what angle to decide. Even if latency is horrible (5000 ms), in the players mind it's acceptable to let the opponent decide what angle to hit at with the cue. It's a hacky solution, but you don't really need to make everything 100% accurate.